# Finding parameter m in quadratic inequality

Tags: inequality

I can't find the solution to the following problem:
Find parameter *m* such that $2x^2+mx-5<0$ is true for $x\in(-1,1)$.
How to approach these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2x^2+mx-5<0$ for all $x$ in the interval $(-1,1)$ means that you must have $\Delta>0$ (since otherwise you'll either have only one root, or the function will be always positive or always negative for any real number $x$).

Now you can calculate $\Delta=b^2-4ac=m^2+40>0$

So this first condition ($\Delta>0$) is satisfied for all values of $m$.

The second condition is that the roots must be $\pm 1$, so $x=\frac{-m \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2(2)}=\pm 1$

This gives you that $\pm \sqrt{m^2+40}=m \pm 4$

Squaring both sides you get $m=\pm 3$

Comment: $m = \pm 3$ is not the correct solution.

Comment: There might be a mistake in the calculation sonewhere, I made it all in my head and so quickly, so you can check that up and correct it. Thank you @Martin R

Answer (score 0):

If this should for all $x$ with $x\in (-1,1)$ true,then you can plug in for instance $$x=\frac{1}{2}$$
You have two inequalities
$$-1<-\frac{m}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{4}+\frac{5}{2}}<1$$ and

$$-1<-\frac{m}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{4}+\frac{5}{2}}<1$$

Answer (score 0):

If you were given the value of $m$ and were asked to find the possible range of values of $x$, how would you proceed?
Get an interval for $x$ so $2x^2 + mx - 5 \implies a<x<b$ where $a$ and $b$ depend upon the value of $m$ and then choose a value of $m$ that gives the range of values of $x$ as $-1<x<1$. Note that a larger interval like $2<x<1.5$ would also answer you question because the inequality $2x^2 + mx - 5<0$ would still be satisfied for $-1<x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

This means one root of this quadratic $f(x)$ should be $<-1$ and the other one should be $>1$ and the roots should be real So we have three conditions:
$B^2 >4AC$, $f(-1)<0$ and $f(1)<0$. So we have $m^2>-10$ (always true as $m$ is real), then $f(-1)<0 \Rightarrow  m>-3$ and $f(1)<0 \Rightarrow m<3$. So the required domain of $m$ is $(-3,3).$

Comment: $f(\pm 1) \le 0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic polynomial $p(x) = 2x^2+mx-5$ is negative on the open interval $(-1, 1)$ if and only if
$$
\begin{align}
 &p(-1) \le 0 \text{ and } p(1) \le 0 \\
\iff &m - 3 \le 0 \text{ and } -m - 3 \le 0 \\
\iff &-3 \le m \le 3 \, .
\end{align}
$$